# Trigger SQL Server insertar/actualizar campo de una tabla valide si se encuentra en otra tabla

Tags: trigger

mi duda es la siguiente: Tengo 3 tablas

Tabla_ArticulosLote
Producto
Almacen
Lote
Fisico

Tabla_MaestroArticulo
Producto

Tabla_SaldosArticulo
Producto
Almacen
Cantidad

Lo que busco es que al momento de realizar un insert/update en Tabla_ArticulosLote valide que dicho producto se encuentre en la Tabla_MaestroArticulo de ser asi actualizar el campo cantidad en Tabla_ArticulosLote e insertar un registro en Tabla_SaldosArticulo.

Espero se haya entendido.
Gracias